# How can I calculate the length and the width of a rectangle if the four coordinates of its vertices are given?

Tags: geometry

I am given the four coordinates of a rectangle's vertices. Now , I need to calculate the length and the width of the rectangle. One way that I have tried is to pick a point and calculate the distances between it and the other three points. But now how do I identify the length and the width from these three points as I may pick the diagonal distance wrongly from these points ?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a Python question, more of a geometry question but I'll give it a shot. From Wikipedia:

> In geometry, a hypotenuse is the longest side of a right-angled
> triangle, the side opposite the right angle. The length of the
> hypotenuse can be found using the Pythagorean theorem, which states
> that the square of the length of the hypotenuse equals the sum of the
> squares of the lengths of the other two sides.

I think you could grab any three points, calculate the distance between all of them. The longest should be the hypotenuse and therefore the "garbage" point to discard. Now you know the width and length!

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal will be the longest. You can just sort these 3 lengths and pick 2 shortest.